# How do you calculate the probability of seeing the same image in a set of 5 when the set is drawn randomly?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

- Given a webpage that displays 5 images drawn at random
- And given a pool of 70 images
- And assuming each image has an equally likely chance of being drawn
- And assuming if an image is drawn for 1 of the 5 slots it can’t appear in any of the other 4
- If you chose a single image to track
- What is the probability of seeing that image over many page refreshes?

I formulated this problem as:

```
P(T) = P(Tdraw1) + P(Tdraw2 | Tdraw1') + P(Tdraw3 | Tdraw2') + P(Tdraw4 | Tdraw3') + P(Tdraw5 | Tdraw4')
```

…but the resulting probability seems to be off from the actual. I count
1,452,361,680 possible outcomes (70 * 69 * 68 * 67 * 66) with
103,740,120 containing the target image. Which would mean a
probability of 0.07142857143.

Using the formulated equation, though, I get a probability of
0.0735742689955004.

Where did I go wrong?

I defined these base probabilities:

```
P(Tdraw1) = 1/70
P(Tdraw2) = 1/69
P(Tdraw3) = 1/68
P(Tdraw4) = 1/67
P(Tdraw5) = 1/66
```

Comment: There's nothing to compute.  By the definition of (uniform) probability, any element of an event with count $k$ in a pool of size $n$ has a $k/n$ chance of appearing.  In this question, $k/n=5/70=0.07142857\ldots.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer should be 5/70 = 0.0714286.
Let $T_i$ be the indicator for drawing your specific image, = 1 if it is, =0 if it is not, i = 1 to 5.
$p=Pr(T_1=1) + Pr(T_2=1|T_1=0)Pr(T_1=0) +...+ Pr(T_5 = 1| T_1 = 0, T_2=0, T_3=0, T_4=0)Pr(T_1=0,T_2=0,T_3=0,T_4=0)$

$= 1/70 +1/69 * 69/70 +...+1/66*66/67*67/68*68/69*69/70$

$=5/70$

$ = 103740120/1452361680 $

Your formula is wrong. Here is the formula I used (Total Probability Theorem). If you like, you can search on internet and get detailed explanation.

$P(B)=P(B|A_1)P(A_1)+...+P(B|A_n)P(A_n)$